# Selectors for React app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, css-selectors, cucumber, capybara

I need to write tests on React app. I've never written tests for React app before and I do not know how to find elements ( due to classes change all time). I would appreciate any hint how can I do it. ( I'm using Capybara + Cucumber + Rails if it matters) . Thank you

Comment: You are asking too many "getting started" questions, which are all too broad for this site. Please review [ask] again.

Answer (score 0):

In react app, You can easily add test data attribute and that's act as ID  and easy to Identify and write test against it .

```
<div data-test-id="myDiv">...</div>
```